# How to get the time in iOS Programming

Tags: objective-c, ios

I wanted to get random numbers according to time. How do you get the current time in iOS Programming for the iPhone?

Answer (score 11):

`NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];`  **OR** `NSDate *now = [NSDate date];`
an NSDate object by default will be initialised to the current date.

Answer (score 6):

in addition to the existing answers:

`gettimeofday` for high accuracy

*or*

`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` if you want a fairly high level interface without an object.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually very simple, refer to [this dev document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html)

Also, you seem fairly new to iOS dev and seem to be having problems on basic things, I would suggest downloading from the iTunes Store the Stanford iTunes U iOS programming course

Answer (score 0):

use `NSDate *currentTime=[NSDate date];` and use `NSDateFormatter` class object to convert the time to your time format.

Answer (score 0):

This give the Current date

```
NSDate *curentDate=[NSDate date];
```