# iOS: How to Get A Device's Current Time To Perform An Action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nstimer

What's the best way to get the a user's current time (12:00pm etc) in order to perform an action? I have a game where I'd like to display night-time images if the current time for a user is between 8pm - 5am.

Comment: See [How To Get The Time In iOS programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278228/how-to-get-the-time-in-ios-programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];

NSString *hourCountString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

int hourCountInt = [hourCountString intValue];

//time between 8PM - 5AM.
if(hourCountInt > 20 || hourCountInt < 5)
{
    NSLog(@"display night-time images");
}
```

Comment: A date formatter is not very performant. Use `NSDateComponents` instead to extract the values you need (and they are already `int`, no need for conversion).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight way would be:

```
NSCalendar *calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
```

I do like helperfunctions, so you could something like this, if you need this function more frequent and want to keep your code bit clean:

```
- (void) getHour:(NSInteger *)hour andMinute:(NSInteger *)minute fromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

    *hour = [dateComponents hour];
    *minute = [dateComponents minute];
}
```

Then call the function like this, where hour and minute could be common class variables:

```
NSInteger hour, minute;
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
[self getHour:&hour andMinute:&minute fromDate:date];
```